# Python Inheritence from constructor

Tags: python, inheritance, parent-child, subclass, super

person.py

```
class Person:
   """---A class representing a person---"""
   # Person constructor
   def __init__(self,n,a): 
       self.full_name = n
       self.age = a
class Student(Person):
    # Student constructor   
    def __init__(self,n,a,s):
       Person.__init__(self,n,a)
       self.school = s
```

driver.py

```
from person import *
    a = Student("Alice", 19, "Univ")
```

It throws `TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`
I tried to change Student class to the following:

```
class Student(Person):
        # Student constructor   
        def __init__(self,n,a,s):
           super().__init__(n,a)
           self.school = s
```

The error still exists.

Why does this happen? Is `super()` keyword required to add new attributes?

EDIT: The problem is solved. There was an indentation issue in the source code rendering this strange behavior, hence the question should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```py
Person.__init__(self,n,a)
```

Is the problem. Recall that methods are automatically passed a reference to themselves, so you just passed a second one.

There's also a well-established pattern for this:

```py
class Person
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, school, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.school = school

student = Student('Washington Elementary', "Johnny Go'gettem", 10)
```

although note that simply removing your reference to `self` in the `Person.__init__` call inside `Student.__init__` would be sufficient.

---

Note that you can override the default method behavior with a couple of decorators that become quite useful in certain situations. Neither apply here, but just a bit of knowledge to tease your brain a bit:

```py
def SomeClass:
    attr = "class-scoped"

    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = "instance-scoped"

    def some_method(self):
        return self.attr == "instance-scoped"

    @classmethod
    def some_classmethod(cls):
        return cls.attr == "class-scoped"

    @staticmethod
    def some_staticmethod():
        return "I'm not given a \"self\" parameter at all!"
```

`classmethod`s are particularly useful as alternate constructors

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    @classmethod
    def from_tuple(cls, tup) -> "Person":
        """Expects a tuple of (name, age) and constructs a Person"""
        name, age = tup
        return cls(name, age)

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, dct) -> "Person":
        """Expects a dictionary with keys "name" and "age" and constructs a Person"""
        try:
            name = dct['name']
            age = dct['age']
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError(f"Dictionary {dct} does not have required keys 'name' and 'age'")
        else:
            return cls(name, age)
```

Comment: I figured the problem is not with the constructor itself....It is with some bad indentation from the source code that I write.  I accidentally add spaces or tabs for comments which renders bad behavoir in logic. After removing the spaces everything works fine. I just couldn't wrap my head around writing Java or C figuring out how indentation or spaces count in Python!

Comment: @Jerry213 indentation will change behavior, but the error message you mentioned is expected given the code you posted, whose indentation appears to be correct. Consider whitespace in Python equivalent to curly braces in Java/C -- it'll help :)